# Рандомные вопросы в тесте

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код:

```
<b>Вопрос 1</b> <br><br>
      <input name=v1 onclick="true_1()" type="radio">Правильный ответ
      <br><br>
      <input name=v1 onclick="false_1()" type="radio">Неправильный ответ
      <br><br><div id="1"></div><br>          
      <hr>

<b>Вопрос 2</b> <br><br>
      <input name=v2 onclick="true_2()" type="radio">Правильный ответ
      <br><br>
      <input name=v2 onclick="false_2()" type="radio">Неправильный ответ
      <br><br><div id="2"></div><br>          
      <hr>
```

И функции:

```
  function false_1() {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Неверно";
  }

  function false_2() {
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "Неверно";
  }
```

И

```
      function true_1() {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Верно";
  }

  function true_2() {
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "Верно";
  }
```

На деле на каждый вопрос - одна функция `true` и одна `false`. Это необходимо, вопрос в другом. Как сделать, чтобы выдавалось лишь, например, 8 рандомных вопроса? И соответственно сохранились бы все запросы по `id`, т.е. если вопрос 2 вызывал функцию `false_2` и `true_2`, то и должен вызывать.

Comment: Недостаточно информации. В каком виде хранятся вопросы? Как получается доступ к ним? Откуда берутся?

Comment: Так в коде все есть. Вместо "Вопрос 1" будет нормальный вопрос. Вместо "Правильный ответ" - будет один из вариантов ответа (который правильный), тоже самое с "неправильный ответ", только там будет неправильный вариант ответа. Это все видно на экране - нажимаешь на один из вариантов и запускается функций true() или false() и далее в div id=1 (номер вопроса) пишется комментарий "Верно" или "Неверно"

Comment: А, вот оно что. То есть на странице будет, скажем, 100 вопросов, и 92 из них нужно скрыть?

Comment: maybe) скрыть может не совсем подходит, нужно выдать из 100 вопросов 8 рандомных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для каждого вопроса делаем тег `div` и помечаем классом `question`

```
<div class="question">
    <b>Вопрос 1</b> <br><br>
    <input name=v1 onclick="true_1()" type="radio">Правильный ответ
    <br><br>
    <input name=v1 onclick="false_1()" type="radio">Неправильный ответ
    <br><br><div id="1"></div><br>
</div>          
<div class="question">
    <b>Вопрос 2</b> <br><br>
    <input name=v2 onclick="true_2()" type="radio">Правильный ответ
    <br><br>
    <input name=v2 onclick="false_2()" type="radio">Неправильный ответ
    <br><br><div id="2"></div><br>          
</div>
```

По умолчанию класс `question` скрыт

```
.question {
    display: none;
}
```

Получаем массив всех вопросов и показываем случайные 6.

```
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
var questionsArray = Array.from(questions);

for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {
     /* случайно определяем номер элемента который необходимо показать */
     var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionsArray.length);
     /* показываем случайный */
     questionsArray[ran].style.display = "block"; 
     /* удаляем показанный элемент из выборки, что бы он не попал второй раз */
     questionsArray.splice(ran,1);
}
```

Comment: все работает, однако он показывает случайный 1 вопрос

Comment: @user278370 поправил. Почему-то возврат `getElementsByClassName` не массив а что-то другое и на него splice не работало.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин тогда `var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionsArray.length);`

Comment: @Igor да, спасибо

Comment: @user278370 теперь работает

Comment: да, все работает, спасибо!

Comment: @user278370 там был лишний код, забыл убрать после рефакторинга, берите новый, в старом была ошибка и делался двойной массив.

Comment: а, взял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Предполагая, что на странице присутствует `n`-ное количество вопросов, а необходимо оставить случайные `m` из них, можно поступить следующим образом.

Сначала дожидаемся загрузки контента DOM, далее получаем список всех вопросов и скрываем `n - m` из них (комментарии будут в коде):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var questions = document.qeurySelectorAll("b"), // получаем список вопросов. Здесь я просто беру все теги `b` исходя из приведенного HTML
        numberOfQuestions = questions.length, // это будет `n` (см. выше)
        hiddenQuestions = []; // здесь будут храниться уже скрытые вопросы

    while (hiddenQuestions.length < 9) { // пока скрытых вопросов меньше `m` (см. выше) + 1
        var num = Math.random() * numberOfQuestions | 0; // генерируем случайный номер вопроса, который будет удален

        if (questions[num]) { // проверяем, существует ли такой вопрос (может его уже удалили ранее, Math.random() может генерировать одно и то же число)
            questions[num].remove(); // удаляем вопрос со страницы
            hiddenQuestions.push(num); // помечаем вопрос как удаленный, запихивая его в массив к удаленным вопросам. Далее по кругу, пока не будет удалено 8 вопросов (в данном случае).
        }
    }
});
```

Единственное только что я здесь удаляю именно тело вопроса (сам вопрос), варианты ответов при этом остаются. Решение - обернуть каждый вопрос в отдельный тег и работать уже и ними:

```
<div class="q">
    <b>Вопрос 1</b> <br><br>
          <input name=v1 onclick="true_1()" type="radio">Правильный ответ
          <br><br>
          <input name=v1 onclick="false_1()" type="radio">Неправильный ответ
          <br><br><div id="1"></div><br>          
          <hr>
</div>
```

И получать список вопросов как `document.querySelectorAll("div.q")`, например.

Comment: Не тестировал. Потому что лень. Вы мне скажете, работает ли. Если нет - будем выяснять причину.